# SQL Server Count Consecutive Preceding Rows based on Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is difficult question for me to write out.

I have a table like below:

| Date | ItemNumber | FlagA | FlagB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 101 | Y | N |
| 2020-01-02 | 101 | N | N |
| 2020-01-03 | 101 | Y | N |
| 2020-01-04 | 101 | Y | N |
| 2020-01-05 | 101 | Y | Y |
| 2020-01-01 | 102 | Y | N |
| 2020-01-02 | 102 | N | N |
| 2020-01-03 | 102 | N | N |
| 2020-01-04 | 102 | Y | Y |

My goal is to count the consecutive dates where FlagA = Y including and preceding the date where FlagB = Y for each ItemNumber. The last date for each ItemNumber in the table will always have FlagB = Y.

I'm trying to achieve this by adding an additional column:

| Date | ItemNumber | FlagA | FlagB | RunningCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 101 | Y | N | 0 |
| 2020-01-02 | 101 | N | N | 0 |
| 2020-01-03 | 101 | Y | N | 1 |
| 2020-01-04 | 101 | Y | N | 2 |
| 2020-01-05 | 101 | Y | Y | 3 |
| 2020-01-01 | 102 | Y | N | 0 |
| 2020-01-02 | 102 | N | N | 0 |
| 2020-01-03 | 102 | N | N | 0 |
| 2020-01-04 | 102 | Y | Y | 1 |

I'm on SQL Server 2012 but do not have a lot of experience with window functions. I've tried several things including:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN [FLagB] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
              over (partition by [ItemNumber],[FlagB] 
                   order by [Date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [RunningCount]
```

and:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN [FLagB] = 'Y' THEN [ItemNumber] END) 
              over (PARTITION BY [ItemNumber] 
                   order by [Date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [RunningCount]
```

but these haven't gotten correct results.

There may be a better way to go about this - I don't need to add the new column to the table, I only need a query that provides the count for each ItemNumber.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want an enumeration of `flagA = Y` for the most recent uninterrupted sequence.  That would be:

```
select t.*,
       (case when grp = 0 and flagA = 'Y'
             then row_number() over (partition by grp, flagA order by date) 
             else 0
        end) as runningCount
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when flagA = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by itemNumber order by date desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately this did not work for me. An error is thrown when trying to alias part of the case statement as 'seqnum'. Removing that adds a count starting at 1 for the first date of the first ItemNumber through the last date, then returns 0s for the rest of the ItemNumbers and dates.

Comment: @sprVUHL . . . I removed that.